# chaining activities leads to OOM

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I was tasked to maintain an app that opens a separate activity for anything the user did. yes it is an old app and I'm planning to upgrade it soon.

During profiling, I found that the graphics memory is taking up a LOT when opening the same activity (different data and all).

I am using the standard `recyclerview` with a library named rv-joiner for multi adapters, and Glide for loading images.

The problem is, I have tried emptying the `recyclerview` and clearing data on Pause hoping that memory would clear up, but it did not work.

I also tried using `Glide.get(context).clearMemory()`, same result.

Are there any suggestions to Improve the memory management?

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<data>

</data>


<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/backgroundColor"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/applicationBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layoutDirection="ltr"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"

            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/post_cover"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@null"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:tint="#66000000"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:alpha="1.0"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:minHeight="56dp"
                android:theme="@style/toolBarStyle"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar_text"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textDirection="ltr"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/action_share"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/action_favorite"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/action_share"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"

                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/action_favorite"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_action_share" />


                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_post"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Emptying recycler view is not reasonable as it uses only 5-8 views with default settings. Possibly each view is pretty heavy. Just populate adapter with one, two, three etc. items and see how much memory it consumes.
2. Glide is a great image processing lib (not only image downloader) so use all of it's powers. You can start with downsampling images and changing it's size. Next - check if there are any bitmaps. They consumes lots of memory, so it's better to convert them to something like drawables.
3. Lottie and other animation processing libs. I'm using lottie in one of my projects and I've noticed that the heavier animation is the slow is UI. So if you've got one - reduce json of animation to max 50 kb.
4. Multithreading and concurrency. From my experience I can say that lots of developers do too much work on UI thread. Separate business logic and UI logic to avoid slow UI. Better use MVVM pattern for that with Android Jetpack.
5. Streams. Close all streams in onPause() (including cursors, etc.) as they consumes lots of process resources.
6. Context. Just don't store your context anywhere in app.
7. Use large heap. Add android:largeheap="true" to application tag in manifest.

That's general rules, but if I were you I would simply put lots of breakpoints and monitor memory consumption after each executed line.

Comment: I did more profiling, apparently inflating the layout alone without data takes about 40MB, with data it takes 60MB.

Switching to a fragment based layout should improve the performance, I assume?

Comment: 40 mb of pure views is to much. Can you post you layout here? Also 20 mb is pretty much too. Maybe you need to split your data objects into separate models

Comment: please check the Edit @Arthur

Comment: @Ibrahim as far as I understood you're trying to use data binding. First of all get rid of it as it's consumes not only memory resources but processors ether. Also keep in mind that data binding in android for today is properly work only in one way (when you getting data from views, not setting it into views). Also try to disable all "magic" libs like data binding, dagger, rxJava or their equivalents as it could and in many cases make to match work and consumes to much memory. By disabling/getting rid I mean totally exclude them from your project to be sure they have 0 influence on your code